# Как проверить число на вхождение в диапазон включительно?

Tags: php

Есть диапазоны чисел, например от 84131840 до 84140031 и таких диапазонов довольно много (около 100) нужно проверить есть ли это число в каком-то из всех диапазонов.
Есть ли вариант кроме цикла с отдельным сравнением для каждого диапазона?

Comment: промежутки пересекаются? можно ли их отсортировать по началу?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman вообще эти числа это результат работы функции ip2long они не пересекаются, но возможно одни входят в другие. Не знаю как проверять вхождение диапазона в диапазон...

Comment: @marrk2 А чем цикл-то не угодил? 100 итераций для современных серверов - это не серьезно

Answer (score 1):

Отсортируйте их по началу и используйте бинарный поиск. Эффективность поиска будет примерно O(log n).

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению.

Comment: @AK а что бы являлось ответом на вопрос?

Comment: Ну как что -- код, который реализует то, что вы написали словами.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman а есть ли в этом решении смысл? Оно, конечно, красивое, но мне кажется, оно в данном случае усложняет задачу. Тут же не было речи о том, как ускорить поиск. По крайней мере, в вопросе этого не прозвучало. Как мне показалось, автор хотел узнать способ, как не прописывать вручную все эти числа в сравнении. А писать вместо этого бинарное дерево...

Comment: @Matty автор спрашивал про перебор всех элементов в цикле. я предложил отсортировать элементы, а не строить дерево.